USB to MIDI hack?
I want to buy an electronic vibes set. Trouble is, its MIDI out also connects it to the power it needs from the computer.
I need it for gigs, so don't want to take any sort of computer with me - I already have several MIDI modules, all with the oldish 5-pin DINs. Which would have worked nicely had the vibes had a 5-pin DIN out. Even if there's an adapter, it'll occupy that port, so I'll get no power to the vibes.
Is there a hack that anyone uses that obviates use of a computer on stage.
The model I'm interested in is the Pearl EM1, but I think the only other model (MalletKat) has exactly the same issues. Reading buyers' comments, the lack of DIN ports is a big turn off.

Knowing the exact model you're considering would help a lot.

Thanks for the update. It looks like with the Pearl EM1 you need a USB MIDI host that could be either a dedicated device or a computer. I don't understand why you think why MalletKat would have the same issue, since the specifications list MIDI and product photos show a pair of big round DIN connectors labeled "MIDI".

@ojs - thanks for that. I probably got mixed up doing some homework. But at something like twice the price, the MalletKat sports some very expensive DINs!

That's quite a lot if the products are otherwise equal. The product page https://pearldrum.com/eu/products/electronics/malletstation/malletstation-em1 recommends KMI MIDI Expander so it should be tested to work and those go for $39.

There are four solutions that I have used for those cases:

Retrokits, with their RK006 (small, uses the small MIDI-over-TRS cables, so you'd need the proper adapters),
CME - they have a whole range of MIDI routers, including their amazing wireless MIDI-over-Bluetooth lineup;
There are Eurorack modules with midi-host functionality (I use the Squarp Hermod) - but if you are not into Eurorack, then you probably shouldn't even try :)
MPC One - it's not worth getting one just for this, but it works surprisingly well as a MIDI/USB-MIDI-Host/USB-MIDI-Device/CV combo


Two solutions:

Buy a controller with MIDI outputs, such as Mallet KAT 8.5 Pro

Buy a converter device, such as Miditech USB MIDI Host. Verify that the current provided is sufficient for your controller.


I have absolutely no opinion on these particular two units. I found them by searching the internet and either of them may solve your problem.

I looked at the MalletKat and thought it only had usb for power and midi. Seems the other vibes available is the Pearl, with a similar arrangement. But thanks for the heads up, I'll report later. Miditech is a possibility - would that, with a DC adapter, power the vibes somehow?

@Tim from the manual "The USB MIDI HOST device's USB port (USB HOST) provides a standard USB 5V 500mA current output". Please verify that it is sufficient for the controller you want to buy. Likely it is, but it's better to check. As I wrote, this is not an equipment recommendation, please read manuals and reviews. Maybe another product of the same kind would suit you better.
